# Find the address of a specific user using Microsoft bot-builder

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I would like to open new conversations with users using the Microsoft Bot Builder on the Skype for Business channel. The only information I have is the user id (sip:user@domain.com)

In all the examples I could find, it is needed to save the conversation id/address of a user in a previous conversation to send a new message to this user.

How to create a new conversation as a bot to a user knowing only his id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you stated the userId is required to send a message to the user. A new conversation can be created by the framework but ultimately, you can't do anything without the userId and to obtain this the user has to contact your bot first. This is only true for channels like Skype. Other channels like E-mail just use the email address as an id. Skype uses a GUID as the id for their users. This is done so bots can't randomly add themselves to any user on Skype. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/resources-identifiers-guide#channel-account)

This doesn't mean you have to necessarily wait for the user to start a conversation. Whenever a user adds a bot to their contact list an event is send to the bot. This is the `ContactRelationUpdate` event. It warns the bot that a user has added the bot and the bot can then respond accordingly. Once this event is thrown you can obtain the userId from the activity and do whatever you want with it. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-activities#activity-types-in-the-bot-builder-sdk-for-net)